# Ruby on Rails: serialize Hash incredibly slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, hash

I've got a simple model called "Search" used for storing searches. It captures the URL params and stores them in an attribute :search_criteria, which is serialized as a Hash:

```
serialize :search_criteria, Hash
```

This all works perfectly, but it performs horribly. For only 5 objects, the following statements take roughly 0.2 seconds.

```
start = Time.now
SavedSearch.all.map(&:search_criteria)
puts Time.now - start
```

If, however, I remove the serialize line (such that search_criteria returns a string) the statements take only 0.002 seconds. That's 2 orders of magnitude difference for deserializing a Hash!!

What's happening here?

Rails.version = 3.2.8
Ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Is it the same with a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` ?

Comment: is it the same if you repeat the test multiple times without restarting the console?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly the same for each run: 2 orders of magnitude slower than without the call to serialize.

Comment: Has anyone been able to reproduce this?

Comment: I tried this again on multiple systems, and it is the same everywhere. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Thank you @rhomeister for sharing both your question and answer here. It's rather sad that today, almost 5 years later, I was not able to find a better solution to this issue. Lesson learnt, I will avoid YAML like the plague from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Active Record is probably laying on a lot of overhead and from this, looks like overkill. As it loops, its instantiating every object in SavedSearch, then assessing the attributes it needs to create, then it does the map.

If you know the exact structure, which seems to be stored in 'search_criteria', then simply store it in YAML in a text attribute. That should be a lot faster.

Comment: Both versions are instantiating SavedSearch, but in one scenario I removed the line "serialize :search_criteria, Hash". So the bottleneck seems to ly in the deserializing of the Hash, not in the instantiation of objects from DB.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the YAML parser. Deserializing YAML is *incredibly slow*. I've solved this by serializing the search_criteria hash as JSON, instead of YAML. It is now rougly 100x faster.

For some additional reading material, have a look at http://iprog.com/posting/2009/10/ruby-on-rails-performance-series-intro-yaml

Comment: Note that JSON has drawbacks, such as not supporting symbols and some other ruby-specific objects.

Comment: Also you should ask yourself why you are using serialized attributes if performance is an issue. You should probably extract this into a separate DB model or use PostgreSQL's hstore extension which supports key-value storage in postgres. You could also write a scope that doesn't select your serialized attribute. Then when you don't need that attribute you can use that scope and AR should be much faster than any other solution.